# IPython (or Numpy) Malloc Error

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Python 2.7

I recently updated a number of Python packages, including NumPy, SciPy, and IPython. After doing so, I discovered that if I tried to open the IPython HTML Notebook I got the error message:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1029b7580: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

From the research I have done, this appears to be a C++ problem, and thus nothing to do with IPython itself. I've had it suggested that NumPy might be the culprit. I should add that the new version of SciPy failed to install properly, which may or may not be related.

Has anyone else run into the same problem?

Comment: How are you starting the notebook (are you using the pylab flag), and at what point does it fail (starting the server, or trying to open a notebook)?